# How to parse string array in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a javascript in the html to render the html on client. I know how to do it using JSON. My question is: Is it possible without JSON?

For example, my server will reply array such as `[["good", "bad"],["first", "second", "third"]]` using a servlet.  I mention String array in topic, because the `xmlhttp.responseText` is regarded as a text or string.  So in javascript, how do I convert this result into array variable?

Using JSON, my server has to reply

```
{
   "1": ["good", "bad"],
   "2": [....]
}
```

I just wanted to see whether we can avoid this key string.

Comment: I think `[["good", "bad"],["first", "second", "third"]]` is valid JSON.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking exactly..

Do you want to change the json response into a javascript object?

Comment: Thank you @Oriol.  Glad to know that.  I think you had answered my question.

Comment: Your Array of Arrays of Strings is perfectly valid JSON already. There's no need to convert to key/value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, JSON has [quote](http://www.json.com/):

> two primary data structures: ordered lists (recognized as 'arrays')
>   and name/value pairs (recognized as 'objects')

JSON objects are written inside curly brackets and can contain multiple key/value pairs.
JSON arrays are written inside square brackets (elements of the array can be basic types like number or string but also objects or arrays).

(from http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

So `[["good", "bad"],["first", "second", "third"]]` is in JSON format and doesn't need to be converted to an object.